# Is there a built-in KL divergence loss function in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, statistics, tensorflow, entropy

I have two tensors, `prob_a` and `prob_b` with shape `[None, 1000]`, and I want to compute the KL divergence from `prob_a` to `prob_b`. Is there a built-in function for this in TensorFlow?  I tried using `tf.contrib.distributions.kl(prob_a, prob_b)`, but it gives:

> NotImplementedError: No KL(dist_a || dist_b) registered for dist_a type Tensor and dist_b type Tensor

If there is no built-in function, what would be a good workaround?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that your input tensors `prob_a` and `prob_b` are probability tensors that sum to 1 along the last axis, you could do it like this:

```
def kl(x, y):
    X = tf.distributions.Categorical(probs=x)
    Y = tf.distributions.Categorical(probs=y)
    return tf.distributions.kl_divergence(X, Y)

result = kl(prob_a, prob_b)
```

A simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
a = np.array([[0.25, 0.1, 0.65], [0.8, 0.15, 0.05]])
b = np.array([[0.7, 0.2, 0.1], [0.15, 0.8, 0.05]])
sess = tf.Session()
print(kl(a, b).eval(session=sess))  # [0.88995184 1.08808468]
```

You would get the same result with

```
np.sum(a * np.log(a / b), axis=1)
```

However, this implementation is a bit buggy (checked in Tensorflow 1.8.0).

If you have zero probabilities in `a`, e.g. if you try `[0.8, 0.2, 0.0]` instead of `[0.8, 0.15, 0.05]`, you will get `nan` even though by Kullback-Leibler definition `0 * log(0 / b)` should contribute as zero.

To mitigate this, one should add some small numerical constant. It is also prudent to use `tf.distributions.kl_divergence(X, Y, allow_nan_stats=False)` to cause a runtime error in such situations.

Also, if there are some zeros in `b`, you will get `inf` values which won't be caught by the `allow_nan_stats=False` option so those have to be handled as well.

Comment: Your arrays `a` and `b` seems to sum to 1 on the last axis, not on the first

Comment: Yes, it would have been better to say "along axis 1", or even better, the last axis. I meant axis 1 when I wrote "along the first axis", as there is also axis 0.

I'll edit the answer. Thanks!

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'distributions'`

Answer (score 7):

For there is softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits, there is no need to optimize on KL.

```
KL(prob_a, prob_b)  
  = Sum(prob_a * log(prob_a/prob_b))  
  = Sum(prob_a * log(prob_a) - prob_a * log(prob_b))  
  = - Sum(prob_a * log(prob_b)) + Sum(prob_a * log(prob_a)) 
  = - Sum(prob_a * log(prob_b)) + const 
  = H(prob_a, prob_b) + const
```

If prob_a is not const. You can rewrite it to the sub of two entropies.

```
KL(prob_a, prob_b)  
  = Sum(prob_a * log(prob_a/prob_b))  
  = Sum(prob_a * log(prob_a) - prob_a * log(prob_b))  
  = - Sum(prob_a * log(prob_b)) + Sum(prob_a * log(prob_a)) 
  = H(prob_a, prob_b) - H(prob_a, prob_a)
```

Comment: There are cases where target probability `prob_a` changes during the optimisation. Then it becomes not constant.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why it's not implemented, but perhaps there is a workaround. The KL divergence is defined as:

`KL(prob_a, prob_b) = Sum(prob_a * log(prob_a/prob_b))`

The cross entropy H, on the other hand, is defined as:

`H(prob_a, prob_b) = -Sum(prob_a * log(prob_b))`

So, if you create a variable `y = prob_a/prob_b`, you could obtain the KL divergence by calling negative `H(proba_a, y)`. In Tensorflow notation, something like:

`KL = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prob_a, y))`

Comment: KL divergence must be 0 when  `prob_a` = `prob_b`. But last line doesn't give 0.

Comment: Yes, it does. When `prob_a = prob_b`, we get `y = 1`. Then, `H(prob_a, y)` is zero from `log(y)`. Are you saying you checked it using Tensorflow's `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prob_a, y)` and the result was not zero?

Comment: Exactly. TensorFlow's implementation might be slightly different than the actual formula.

Comment: Worth pointing out that softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prob_a,y) does not actually implement H(prob_a,y), it implements H(softmax(a),y). So using softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits will only work if you try to calculate the KL divergence on the activations of a softmax function (prob_a) and have access to the unscaled logits (a)

Answer (score 2):

`tf.contrib.distributions.kl` takes instances of a `tf.distribution` not a `Tensor`.

Example:

```
  ds = tf.contrib.distributions
  p = ds.Normal(loc=0., scale=1.)
  q = ds.Normal(loc=1., scale=2.)
  kl = ds.kl_divergence(p, q)
  # ==> 0.44314718
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have access to logits a and b:

```
prob_a = tf.nn.softmax(a)
cr_aa = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prob_a, a)
cr_ab = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prob_a, b)
kl_ab = tf.reduce_sum(cr_ab - cr_aa)
```

Comment: Not going to work! From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits): "WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax on logits internally for efficiency. *Do not call this op with the output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results*" (emphasis mine)

Comment: Assuming that you have access to logits a and b. This is not calling it on prob_a and prob_b. It is calling it on a and b.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
tf.reduce_sum(p * tf.log(p/q))
```

where p is my actual probability distribution 
and q is my approximate probability distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I used the function from [this code](https://gist.github.com/FelixMohr/a83e57393647dd2971d5ae12bb01f504#file-vae-py) (from [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/teaching-a-variational-autoencoder-vae-to-draw-mnist-characters-978675c95776) Medium post) to calculate the KL-divergence of any given tensor from a normal Gaussian distribution, where `sd` is the standard deviation and `mn` is the tensor.

```py
latent_loss = -0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(1.0 + 2.0 * sd - tf.square(mn) - tf.exp(2.0 * sd), 1)
```