# How can I implement the Kullback-Leibler loss in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, probability, loss

I need to minimize [KL loss](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergenza_di_Kullback-Leibler) in **tensorflow**.

I tried this function `tf.contrib.distributions.kl(dist_a, dist_b, allow_nan=False, name=None)`, but I failed.

I tried to implement it manually:

```
def kl_divergence(p,q):
    return p* tf.log(p/q)+(1-p)*tf.log((1-p)/(1-q))
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KL Divergence in TensorFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863814/kl-divergence-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have there is the cross entropy, KL divergence should be something like:

```
def kl_divergence(p, q): 
    return tf.reduce_sum(p * tf.log(p/q))
```

This assumes that p and q are both 1-D tensors of float, of the same shape and for each, their values sum to 1.

It should also work if p and q are equally sized mini-batches of 1-D tensors that obey the above constraints.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and in case that p and q are multidimensional?

Comment: Do you mean in the case that p and q are mini-batches of distributions that you want to optimize? I think what I have should be fine for that case as well. If it's not that then I would need more context.

Comment: i get nan when i try to compute the division 0/0

Comment: i add a **costant** = 0.00001 to each p and q to avoid nan, is correct?

Comment: @srabb that is one option, you can also do tf.max so it doesn't modify other results, I wonder if there is a better way though

Comment: adding a small const is the version I see in tensorflow examples from Google, I would guess this is marginally faster than doing a max?

Comment: Instead of adding a constant to handle zeros smooth it with an uniform distribution.

Comment: tf.log no longer exists - tf.math.log rather