# Tensorflow: KL divergence for categorical probability distribution

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to calculate the accuracy of my network with KL divergence. The prediction is a k-dimensional probability vector, which shall be compared against a gold-standard probability distribution of the same dimensionality.
I tried this:

```
corr_subj_test = tf.contrib.distributions.kl(pred_subj, y)
accr_subj_test = tf.reduce_mean(corr_subj_test)
```

But eventually get the following error:

> NotImplementedError: No KL(dist_a || dist_b) registered for dist_a
>   type Tensor and dist_b type Tensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the tensorflow [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) and some other Issues that give the same `NotImplementedError` error (like [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2476)) it seems that the `kl()` method does not currently accept that specific combination of parameter types.

If it is possible, you could pass your data to `kl()` in a data type it accepts (maybe transforming your data to achieve so).**

You could also try post it on tensorflow [issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) to discuss about your problem.

** **Edit:**

As suggested and explained by the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863814/kl-divergence-in-tensorflow) question, you can obtain your desired result by using *Cross Entropy* instead with the `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` method, like this:

```
newY = pred_subj/y
crossE = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred_subj, newY)
accr_subj_test = tf.reduce_mean(-crossE)
```

Comment: Enhanced my answer with other alternatives